# Flutter build error: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings, ttcIndex not found

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, visual-studio-app-center

Currently our Flutter builds on MS Appcenter are failing with the following logs:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':appcenter_analytics:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/runner/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/4bf813c12249ada6f409527e3c5fd194/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     /Users/runner/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/4bf813c12249ada6f409527e3c5fd194/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
```

This problem cannot be reproduced locally, there everything works fine. Only the build in Appcenter is failing.

Most of the answers around this problem seem to be about the `compileSdkVersion`, which in our project was already at `28`, I have even tried to change it to `29` to no avail. I have set-up a completely new pipeline in Appcenter, same result. I have changed flutter versions, same result.
Flutter doctor output in the appcenter:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G3020, locale en)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
+ flutter build apk --release
Running "flutter pub get" in s...                                  11.6s
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        
Gradle 5.6.4
```

Thanks!

Comment: try to update compileSdkVersion  to 28 work for me

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and was related to a plugin that doesn't have the recent compile SDK version. You can force that by changing the andoid/build.gradle file and include something like

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.name == "plugin_that_causes_the_issue") {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 28
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error while building the flutter App.

- Open Project structure (File -> Project Structure).
- then in Project SDK select Android API 29 platform.
- Click Ok

It will solve the problem if not then open Android Module in Android Studio (Tools -> Flutter -> Open for editing in Android Studio). and try to build apk from build